# Kivy MapMarkerPopUp not displaying in KV design file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So I am trying to open the map on kivy and display a map marker on the correct lat and long but when I run the program the mapmarker doesnt show up, its not throwing any errors, and I cant find any documentation to help me. I'm newer to kivy, thanks for the help.

***Kivy code***

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView


MapView:
    lat: 10
    lon: 10
    zoom: 10
    on_lat:
        print('lat', self.lat)
    on_lon:
        print('lon', self.lon)

    MapMarkerPopup:
        lon: 10
        lat: 10
```

***Python Code***

```
from kivy.app import App


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass


MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your installation for default marker image marker.png. Possibility is it might be missing at the required path. So you can use custom png file for marker.